# EndOfStreamException Caused By Deserialization

Tags: c#, exception, deserialization, binaryformatter

I'm developing a game using UnityEngine (see what I did there?) and I've been trying to deserialize a file that was serialized by a BinaryFormatter. However, it throws an EndOfStreamException when compiler begins deserializing my file.

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream file = File.Open(myPath);
LevelData lvlData = (LevelData)formatter.Deserialize(file);
```

And this is my `LevelData` class:

```
[Serializable]
class LevelData
{
    public Dictionary<Vector2, Level> levelButtonData = new Dictionary<Vector2, Level>();
}
```

What is it that's wrong here? As a matter of fact, it was working just fine yesterday. I must've changed something accidentally.

**Additional Info**

This is how I serialize it:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
FileStream file = File.Create(myPath);
LevelData lvlData = new LevelData();
lvlData.levelButtonData = this.levelButtonData;
formatter.Serialize(file, lvlData);
file.Close();
```

Comment: What is the content of the file? I guess it is still expecting some data, but it hits EOF already.

Comment: Probably, the file is incorrectly written.

Comment: Sorry, content as in..? It's just this LevelData class with a dictionary being serialized into a dat. file.

Comment: You could try calling `file.Position = 0` before calling `Deserialize`.

Comment: He's saying we need to see the contents of the file you're trying to read.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have source control so you can compare yesterday's version with the current one?

Comment: @MarkAvenius Unfortunately, no.

Comment: Have you changed the content of serialized classes - added/removed properties ?

Comment: Based on the code you submitted, you aren't disposing of `file`. Might there have been an exception in `Serialize` since your last reboot, which would leave `file` open? - adding a using around `FileStream file...` would take care of this for you.

Comment: Do you use the same instance  FileStream file to serialize and deserialize.

Comment: My guess is you changed something down the dependency tree of your LevelData class. Does the error occur even when you create a new dump (serialize a new LevelData) and load it pronto (deserialize it again)?